# Пользовательская сортировка pdoPage

Tags: modx

Пытаюсь релизовать сортировку товаров выводимых через pdoPage. Но сортировка указываемая в GET параметре не применяется

**Вывод идет так:**

```
{'!pdoPage' | snippet : [
      'parents' => $_modx->resource.id,
      'limit' => 9,
      'hideContainers' => true,
      'includeTVs' => 'image,price,old_price',
      'tplPageWrapper' => '@INLINE {include "file:inc/pager.wrap.tpl"}'
      'tplPageActive' => '@INLINE {include "file:inc/pager.page.active.tpl"}',
      'tvPrefix' => '',
      'tpl' => '@INLINE
        <div class="column">
          {include "file:inc/catalog/product.tpl"}
        </div>
      '
      $modx->runSnippet('!Sort')
    ]}
```

**Снипет Sort:**

```
    <?php
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
if($sort == '') {
    $output='&sortby=`{"menuindex":"ASC"}`';
} else {
    $output = '&sortby=`{"'.$sort.'":"'.$_GET['dir'].'"}`';
}
return $output;
```

Пример ссылок:

```
<nav>
  <span>Сортировать по:</span>
  <a href="/vesyi-i-shagomeryi/vesyi-elektronnyie/? 
  sort=pagetitle&amp;dir=DESC">Названию</a>
  <a up="" href="/vesyi-i-shagomeryi/vesyi-elektronnyie/? 
  sort=price&amp;dir=DESC">По цене</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш сниппет надо вызывать внутри вызова `pdoPage`:

```
<?php
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
if($sort == '') {
  $output='{"menuindex":"ASC"}';
} else {
  $output = '{"'.$sort.'":"'.$_GET['dir'].'"}';
}
return $output;
```

А в вызов  `pdoPage` добавьте:

```
&sortby=`[[!sort]]`
```

P.S. Напрямую передавать в вызовы строки пришедшие извне, не лучшая идея, обязательно позаботьтесь о том, чтобы проверить, что sort и dir содержат только допустимые поля, и не содержат ничего другого.

Comment: Так у меня вызывается сниппет Sort внутри pdoPage
$modx->runSnippet('!Sort')
При использовании 'sortby' => $modx->runSnippet('!Sort') результата нет

Comment: Посмотрите лог, в обоих вызовах: `'showLog'=>1` что там передается от сниппета